# example of subspaces involving inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$A+B=\left \{ a+b : a\in A, b\in B \right \}$

Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ be elements of $A$ and let $b_1,\ldots,b_k$ be elements of $B$ be two families of vectors in $C$. Let $A=\operatorname{Span}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ and $b=\operatorname{Span}(b_1,\ldots,b_k)$

**problem**
I have shown that $A+B$ is a subspace of $C$ but I am unsure on some inequalities using dimension of the spaces.

Find subspaces $A_1, B_1$ of $C=\mathbb{R}^3$ of dimension $n=1$ and  $k=2$ such that $\dim(A_1+B_1) <n+k=3$ and an example of a subspace $A_2, B_2$ of $C=\mathbb{R}^3$ of same dimension $n=1$ and $k=2$ but this time so that $\dim(A_2+B_2)=n+k=3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A_1=\{(x,0,0)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$ and $B_1=\{(x,y,0)\mid x,y\in\Bbb R\}$, then $\dim A_1=1$, $\dim B_1=2$, and, since $A_1+B_1=B_1$, $\dim(A_1+B_1)=2$.

But if $A_2=\{(x,0,0)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$ and $B_2=\{(0,x,y)\mid x,y\in\Bbb R\}$, then $\dim A_2=1$, $\dim B_2=2$, and, since $A_2+B_2=\Bbb R^3$, $\dim(A_2+B_2)=3$.

Comment: small question why is $A_1+B_1=B_1$? (first example)

Comment: Because $A_1\subset B_1$. When you have two subspaces $W_1$ and $W_2$ of some vector space, if $W_1\subset W_2$, then $W_1+W_2=W_2$.

Comment: Ok I see. so for the second example $A_2+B_2=R^3$ why does that hold?

Comment: Because if $(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3$, then$$(x,y,z)=\overbrace{(x,0,0)}^{\phantom{A_2}\in A_2}+\overbrace{(0,y,z)}^{\phantom{B_2}\in B_2}.$$